# Merge 2 Resultsets using JDBCTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, oracle9i

I'm modifying a stand alone **Spring 3.0.6** application that uses **JDBCTemplate**. The main problem is that I have to extract information from two different **Oracle** databases for which I created 2 Datasources:

1. Added the 2 datasources in an applicationContext.xml.
2. Created an interface that serves a DAO with 2 final String 
   variables with SQL statements to call the stored procedures 
   and the methods to return the resultsets.
3. Created an implementation class for the DAO in order to 
   execute the stored procedures.

What I have no idea how to do is to get the resultset from the 2 methods and merge them into a **single resultset** so I can present the result as a **final report**.

Comment: Why you want to merge resultsets, but not the Entity collections coming from 2 data source, I think that will be easier to achieve.

Comment: @Yogi Could you elaborate on that ? I don't understand what do you mean when you say "Entity collections". This is not a JPA project is using JDBCTemplate.

Comment: Collection of Object of entities/class, which is representing in report.